# How to make this VBA code - Excel more efficient?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Best regards; I have the following code and I want to make it more efficient, since there are 1,000,000 records to analyze. Thank you very much, apologize for my English grief.

```
Sub test()
Sub test()
    Dim value1 As Worksheet, value2 As Worksheet
    Dim col1 As Long, col2 As Long
    Set value1 = Worksheets(2)
    Set value2 = Worksheets(2)
    For col1 = 2 To value1.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
        For col2 = 2 To value2.Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row
            If value1.Cells(col1, 1).Value = value2.Cells(col2, 2).Value _
                And value1.Cells(col1, 1).Value > 0 Then
                    value1.Cells(col1, 1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You could avoid this entirely and use conditional formatting, if that's an option.

Comment: Conditional formatting is great, as long as you do not have to then filter the data to see which ones are highlighted in yellow. Then the excel freezes.

Comment: You could figure out to do this in memory. The fact youre looping through the objects themselves means this might take forever if the row count is high. Arrays are your friend

Comment: A million rows is  a million rows.  But, to eek out some more performance calculate those last cells outside of the loops and assign them to variables.  Most importantly, turn off auto calculation and screen updating during this.  You are probably paying huge costs doing work that has no value until the macro is done.

Comment: What do you actually want to do? You're looping over the same million rows a million times, if both `value1` and `value2` refer to `Worksheets(2)`? Are you just highlighting dupes across columns?

Comment: wait... it's a million * a million iterations.  Sheesh.  You need an escape condition when you match and color the cell yellow.  add an Exit to the if block.

Comment: Also pretty sure this belongs in CodeReview but whatever

Comment: thanks for the info. I still try to improve the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got bored and did a thing for you.

```
Private Sub utqwdelkdfjsvd()
    Dim rng As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim pickup As Variant
    pickup = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("yoursheetname").usedrange
    For i = LBound(pickup, 1) To UBound(pickup, 1)
        For j = LBound(pickup, 1) To UBound(pickup, 1)
            If pickup(i, 1) = pickup(j, 2) And pickup(i, 1) > 0 Then
                If i = 1 Then
                    rng = "a" & i
                Else
                    rng = rng & ", a" & i
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(rng).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
End Sub
```

Comment: what about the nested loop?  OP is comparing each cell in col A against every cell in Col B -- not just row by row.  (actually, it seems more like a mistake each time I think about it)

Comment: @ryanB.  youre right - i misread it. I got you covered though see edit

Comment: Luckily its a pretty easy addition.

Comment: I like `rng = IIf(i = 1, "a1", rng & ", a" & i)` to save 4 lines :)

Comment: @WolfgangJacques thats because youre smarter than me <3

Comment: Thanks Doug Coats, I'm going to experiment with what you say.

Comment: unfortunately, it seems our concatenated string must be less than 256 characters

Comment: ok, I gave my last contribution to this little conversation :)  Thanks for calling me out on my solution.  Improving that code has been helpful to me.

Comment: Thanks to the whole community for helping me with this case, I have learned a whole world ("local phrase").
I re-express my gratitude. during the weekend I was able to complete the goal thanks to their collaborations.

Comment: Thanks to the whole community for helping me with this case, I have learned a whole world ("local phrase").
I re-express my gratitude. during the weekend I was able to complete the goal thanks to their collaborations.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thank-you Doug Coats for calling me to bigger and better things. I actually learned a lot myself on this one.

This colors up the whole list in about 10 seconds.

The key features of this method are:

Pull the data into memory.
Sort the lists. Ordered data will allow you to
Parse the lists with two iterators that can help keep you from doing unnecessary reads.
attempt to bundle up the 'colorizing' of the cells. This is a slower operation so we minimize the number of times it's needed as best we can.
So I hope the following makes sense with that overview in mind.

```
Sub Yellowizer()
    Debug.Print Now
    ' all this garbge with the extra worksheet is because I was too lazy to hunt up a
    ' decent sort for arrays.  You can improve this if you want.
    Set SourceSheet = ActiveSheet
    Set TempSheet = Worksheets.Add

    'declare some working variables
    Dim rngString As String: '<--- dont use command separators
    rngString = ""
    Dim checkList As Variant
    Dim readList As Variant

    ' Get a sorted array of the values we are going to check against (column "b")
    With TempSheet.Range("A:A")
        .Value = SourceSheet.Range("B:B").Value
        .Sort Key1:=TempSheet.Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
        .RemoveDuplicates 1, xlNo
    End With

    checkList = TempSheet.Range("A1", TempSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown))
    ' Get a sorted array of the values we are going to test (column "a").  Also
    ' bring a reference of where they came from so we can go color the proper field
    readList = SourceSheet.Range("A:B").Value

    For i = 1 To UBound(readList)
        readList(i, 2) = i
    Next i

    With TempSheet.Range("A:B")
        .Value = readList
        .Sort Key1:=TempSheet.Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
    End With

    readList = TempSheet.Range("A:B")
    ' get rid of this working sheet
    TempSheet.Delete
    SourceSheet.Activate
    ' Declare some iterators for reading our arrays
    Dim checkListIterator, readListIterator, checkListMovingLowerBound As Double
    checkListIterator = 1
    readListIterator = 1
    checkListMovingLowerBound = 1

    ' Iterate over the Read list and the Check list.  Take advantage of the
    ' sorted arrays to skip as many reads as possible by advancing the
    ' moving lower bound or by escaping early when matches aren't possible.
    For readListIterator = 1 To UBound(readList)
        For checkListIterator = checkListMovingLowerBound To UBound(checkList)
            If checkList(checkListIterator, 1) < readList(readListIterator, 1) Then
                checkListMovingLowerBound = checkListMovingLowerBound + 1
            Else
                If checkList(checkListIterator, 1) = readList(readListIterator, 1) Then
                    rngString = rngString & "a" & readList(readListIterator, 2) & ", "
                    If Len(rngString) > 180 Then
                        rngString = Left(rngString, Len(rngString) - 2)
                        SourceSheet.Range(rngString).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                        rngString = ""
                    End If
                End If
                'set iterator to finsh this checkList scan and move to next read item
                checkListIterator = UBound(checkList)
            End If
        Next checkListIterator
    Next readListIterator

    rngString = Left(rngString, Len(rngString) - 2)
    SourceSheet.Range(rngString).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    Debug.Print Now
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks to the whole community for helping me with this case, I have learned a whole world ("local phrase").
I re-express my gratitude. during the weekend I was able to complete the goal thanks to their collaborations.

Comment: Thanks Ryan B. for sharing your ingenious ideas. A query, where I place the condition so that the assessed value is greater than zero?

Comment: This would be simplified significantly by adding the len check/criteria to my original post. Sorry would've done it sooner but I wasn't able to actually get in front of a computer till today. Though I would add a few things that maybe you'll like? One of my rules of VBA is dont interact with the applications objects - if you can avoid it. Most things can and should be done in memory. On this point, that implies never activate/select/copy etc etc dont use command separators (pointed out in code edit). Its lazy and makes readability worse. Hope it helps in the future.